# CSS Lint ignore all IE6 and IE7 based errors

Tags: css, lint, csslint

I'm using Sublime Text 3, and [CSS Linter](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter-csslint).

In my settings I've put the ignore rule, and currently there is only the `"outline-none"` rule, I'd like to include all the rules which refer to IE6 and IE7 based errors.

Is there a list what are the IE6 and IE7 rules so that I can put them in the ignore array?

My CSSLint.sublime-settings look like this:

```
// CSSLint rules you wish to ignore. Must be an array. Leave blank to include all default rules.
{
    "ignore": ["outline-none"]
}
```

Comment: Do we still worry about IE6 and 7???  Microsoft has released a report saying that they are no longer going to update old browsers. So only the recent browser will get all the security updates. Tell them to upgrade there browsers for security reasons

Comment: We do not, that's why I need to turn off the annoying error the linter is throwing me ;) Because it's not an error :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To answer my own question, in the end I figured how to do what I need:

```
{
    "user": {
        "debug": false,
        "delay": 0.25,
        "error_color": "D02000",
        "gutter_theme": "Packages/SublimeLinter/gutter-themes/Danish Royalty/Danish Royalty.gutter-theme",
        "gutter_theme_excludes": [],
        "lint_mode": "background",
        "linters": {
            "csslint": {
                "@disable": false,
                "args": [],
                "box-sizing": false,
                "errors": "",
                "excludes": [],
                "ignore": [
                    "outline-none",
                    "box-sizing",
                    "ids",
                    "adjoining-classes",
                    "floats",
                    "qualified-headings",
                    "unique-headings",
                    "important",
                    "universal-selector",
                    "box-model",
                    "font-faces",
                    "font-sizes"
                ],
                "warnings": ""
            },
            "eslint": {
                "@disable": true,
                "args": [],
                "excludes": []
            },
            "jscs": {
                "@disable": true,
                "args": [],
                "excludes": []
            },
            "jshint": {
                "@disable": false,
                "args": [],
                "excludes": [],
                "ignore": [
                    "newcap"
                ],
                "newcap": false,
                "tab_size": 4
            },
            "jslint": {
                "@disable": true,
                "args": [],
                "excludes": [],
                "ignore": [
                    "newcap"
                ],
                "newcap": false
            },
            "php": {
                "@disable": false,
                "args": [],
                "excludes": []
            }
        },
        "mark_style": "outline",
        "no_column_highlights_line": false,
        "passive_warnings": false,
        "paths": {
            "linux": [],
            "osx": [],
            "windows": []
        },
        "python_paths": {
            "linux": [],
            "osx": [],
            "windows": []
        },
        "rc_search_limit": 3,
        "shell_timeout": 10,
        "show_errors_on_save": false,
        "show_marks_in_minimap": true,
        "syntax_map": {
            "html (django)": "html",
            "html (rails)": "html",
            "html 5": "html",
            "php": "html",
            "python django": "python"
        },
        "warning_color": "D02000",
        "wrap_find": true
    }
}
```

Just go to Preferences > Package Settings > SublimeLinter > Settings - User and paste the above in the opened file.

These are the options that I found not to be of practical importance, so I just ignored them.

Hope it helps :)